# Harmonic series derivate - convergent or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

It is known that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln(n)}=\infty$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln(n)\ln(\ln(n))}=\infty$ etc.

But what happens if we consider the following series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\prod_{k=1}^{a(n)}ln^k(n)}$$

(with $ln^k(x)$ describing k iterations and $a(n)$ the maximum possible value such that $ln^{a(n)}(n)>1$

If this is convergent, what function desribes its rate of convergence (i.e. minimum number of terms to reach a given precision), and if it is divergent, what is its rate of divergence (i.e. minimum number of terms to pass a natural number $n$)?

Edit to fix André Nicolas' justified objection.

Edit the second: This series diverges... see [Putnam 2008 A4](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/). That does leave the question about rate of divergence, though!

Comment: Is that what is really wanted? After a (short) while the $\log\log\dots$ is negative, and then the next one gives trouble.

Comment: That... is something I had not considered. For the finite cases that's hand-waved over by just starting high enough, but I'm not sure how to fix that for the derived infinite case. I'll need to think on that. In any case, thanks for the comment!

Comment: Okay, here's the fix, blatantly stolen from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49415/nonexistence-of-boundary-between-convergent-and-divergent-series - which indicates that this is pretty nontrivial question. I'll edit it in.

Comment: You could define $ln^0(n)=n$ and begin the index of the product at $k=0$. Then $a(0)=0$.